# Given $P\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ there is a nonzero $Q\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $H(PQ)\leq M(P)$

Tags: reference-request, polynomials, inequalities

I am looking for a proof (or references) for the following result:

> If $P\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ then there exists a nonzero polynomial $Q\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$
> such that
> $$H(PQ)\leq M(P)$$
> where
> $H(R)=\max\{|a_0|,|a_1|,\dots,|a_n|\}$ and $
> M(R)=|a_n|\prod_{k=1}^n\max\{1,|\alpha_k|\}$ are respectively the height and the Mahler measure of a polynomial $R(x)=\sum_{k=o}^na_kx^k=a_n\prod_{k=1}^n (x-\alpha_k).$

Comments are also welcome.

Comment: This reminded me of: https://carmamaths.org/resources/mahler/docs/144.pdf

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan Thanks, I'll check it out

Comment: An immediately desire is to apply the pigeonhole principle (as in Thue/Siegel lemma): consider all polynomials of degree at most $T$ (for some large $T$) and integer coefficients from 0 to $M(P)$. We want two of them having the same remainder modulo $P$. It remains to bound the number of possible remainders.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Chapter 3 of Jonas Jankauskas's dissertation thesis, entitled ["Heights of Polynomials"](https://epublications.vu.lt/object/elaba:1917005/1917005.pdf), we learn that the inequality

$$\min_{Q \in \mathbb{Z}[x] \setminus \{0\}} H(PQ) \le \lfloor M(P)\rfloor$$

where $P \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $\lfloor r \rfloor$ denotes the integral part of $r \in \mathbb{R}$, follows from [Siegel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel%27s_lemma) [3].

The references given by Jonas Jankauskas are

- [[2]](https://zbmath.org/0405.12021), written in French, which gives a simplified proof of an enhanced [1, Théorème], also written in French,
- [3], written in English.

I can confirm that the original theorem of Martine Pathiaux [1, Théorème] yields the desired result.

Taking more time to parse [3], I might be able to update this answer with the precise statement of [3] which proves the above inequality.

**Key words:** *Reduced height, Siegel's lemma*.

---

**Addendum.** After reading further [3], but still superficially, I didn't find any direct means to derive the desired result from Siegel's lemma. (If $P$ is monic, we can indeed consider a linear homogenous system of equations with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. As I haven't been able to conclude from there, I'll ask around if such an approach can be successful).

The papers [1] and [2] both establish the result for $P$ an **irreducible** polynomial. In her final remark [1, page 13-08], Martin Pathiaux asserts that the reducible case can be addressed by simply "adding more inequations" to her system. This is accurate, but it requires a good understanding of her proof.

For the sake of seeing **a complete proof of the fact referred to by the OP**, I have written below a proof along the lines of [2].
This proof doesn't add anything original. It consists only of the details which quickly convince me that the reducible case holds also true.

**Generalizing [1, Théorème 1] to reducible polynomials.**

Let $P(x) = a_0 + a_1 x +  \cdots + a_d x^d \in \mathbb{C}[x]$. The *height* of $P$ is the real number $H(P) = \max_{i} \vert a_i \vert$.
The *Mahler measure* of $P$ is the real number
$M(P) = \vert a_d \cdot \lambda_1  \cdots \lambda_r \vert$ where $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_r \in \mathbb{C}$ are the roots of $P$ in $\mathbb{C}$ whose complex modulus is at least $1$.

We set ourselves to prove:

> **Claim.** [1, Final remark]
> Let $P \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Then there is $Q \in \mathbb{Z}[x] \setminus \{0\}$ such that $H(PQ) \le M(P)$.

We first mention the two results which have allowed Maurice Mignotte to significantly simplify the original proof of [1, Théorème 1] by Martine Pathiaux.

> **Proposition.** [2, Corollaire 1]
> Let $a_{i,j} \in \mathbb{C}$, with
> $i \in \{1, \dots, m\}, j \in \{1, \dots, n\}$ and
> $L_{i}(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_{i,j} x_j$ for
> $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{C}$. Let $A_i = \max_j \vert a_{i,j} \vert$.
> Let $M \in \mathbb{N}_{> 0}$.
> Then we can find $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{Z}^n \setminus \{0\}$ such that $\vert x_j \vert  \le M$ for every $j \in \{1, \dots, n\}$
> and
> $$\vert L_i(\mathbf{x}) \vert < \sqrt{2n \log(18m)} A_i \frac{M + 1}{(M + 1)^{n/m} - 2}$$
> for every $i \in \{1, \dots, m\}$, provided that $(M + 1)^{n/m} > 2$.

The following lemma is a quantitative version of the [fundamental theorem for symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials).

> **Lemma.** [2, Section III, see remark at the bottom of page 3] Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. Let $Q \in R[x_1, \dots, x_d]$ by a symmetric polynomial.
> Then there is a polynomial $\tilde{Q} \in  R[x_1, \dots, x_d]$, with total degree $\deg(\tilde{Q}) \le \max_i \deg_{x_i}(Q)$ and such that
> $$Q(x_1, \dots, x_d) = \tilde{Q}(e_{1, d}, e_{2, d}, \dots, e_{d,d})$$ where
> $e_{1, d} = \sum_{i = 1}^d x_i, e_{2, d} = \sum_{1 \le i < j \le d} x_i x_j, \dots, e_{d, d} = x_1 \cdots x_d$
> are [the elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) on $x_1, \dots, x_d$.

> *Proof of the lemma.* Revisit one of the classical proofs of the [fundamental theorem for symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials) and
> check in the induction step that $\deg(\tilde{Q}) \le \max_i\deg_{x_i}(Q)$ additionally holds for every $i$.

We are now in position to prove the claim.

> *Proof of the claim.* We can assume that $P$ is not constant, since otherwise the result is trivial. (The result is also obvious if $\deg(P) = 1$, but we won't need this fact).
> We can also assume, without loss of generality, that $P$ is primitive, i.e., the coefficients of $P$ are coprime integers,
> and that the leading coefficient of $P$ is positive.
> As $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a [unique factorization domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain#:%7E:text=7%20References-,Definition,n%20with%20n%20%E2%89%A5%200), we can write
> $P(x) = P_1^{\mu_1}(x) \cdots P_k^{\mu_k}(x)$ where $\mu_l \in \mathbb{N}_{> 0}$ and
> $P_i \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is an irreducible primitive polynomial of degree $d_i > 0$, with positive leading coefficient, for
> every $i \in \{1, \dots, k\}$.
> For $i \in \{1, \dots, k\}$, we denote by $\theta_{i, 1}, \dots, \theta_{i, d_i}$ the roots of $P_i$ in $\mathbb{C}$.
> We shall prove that there exists, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_{> 0}$ sufficiently large, a polynomial
> $D(x) = d_0 + d_1x + \cdots + d_{n - 1}x^{n - 1} \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$
> which satisfies the inequality $\vert d_j \vert \le M(P)$ for every $j \in \{0, \dots, n - 1\}$ together with the equation
> $D^{(\mu)}(\theta_{i, j}) = 0$ for every
> $i \in \{1, \dots, k\}, j \in \{1, \dots, d_i\}$ and $\mu \in \{0, \dots, \mu_i - 1\}$
> where $D^{(\mu)}$ denotes the $\mu$-th derivative of $D$.
> Let us observe that such a polynomial $D$ obviously satisfies $H(D) \le M(P)$. In addition, this polynomial $D$ is divisible by $P$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.
> The fact that $P$ divides $D$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ follows immediately from [Gauss's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomials)).
> The proof of the existence of $D$ is a straightforward application of the method developed in [2].
> We proceed by showing, for all $n$ sufficiently large, the existence of a polynomial
> $D \in \mathbb{Z}[x] \setminus \{0\}$ satisfying the inequations
> $\vert  D^{(\mu)}(\theta_{i, j}) \vert < \epsilon_{i, j, \mu}(n)$ for some upper bound $\epsilon_{i, j, \mu}(n)$
> which can be rendered sufficiently small to enforce $D^{(\mu)}(\theta_{i, j}) = 0$
> for every $i, j$ and $\mu$.
> To this end, we set $M = \lfloor M(P) \rfloor$ and apply the above proposition to the linear forms
> $L_{i, j, \mu}(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{l = 0}^n a_{i, j, \mu, l} x_l$ with
> $a_{i, j, \mu, l} =  \max(l(l - 1) \cdots (l - \mu + 1), 0) \cdot \theta_{i, j}^{l - \mu}$ and $n > 0$. (There are $m = \deg(P)$ such forms.)
> Since we have
> $A_{i, j, \mu} := \max_l \vert a_{i, j, \mu, l} \vert \le \mu_i ! \max(\vert\theta_{i, j}\vert, 1)^{n - 1}$, the above
> proposition provides us with some
> $\mathbf{d} = (d_0, \dots, d_{n - 1}) \in \mathbb{Z}^n \setminus \{0\}$ such that $\vert L_{i, j, \mu}(\mathbf{d}) \vert < \epsilon_{i, j, \mu}(n)$ for every $i, j$ and $\mu$, where
> $$\epsilon_{i, j, \mu}(n) = \sqrt{2n \log(18 \deg(P))}\mu_i ! \frac{\max(\vert\theta_{i, j}\vert^{n - 1}, 1)(M + 1)}{(M + 1)^{n/\deg(P)} - 2}.$$
> Let us set $D(x) := d_0 + d_1x + \cdots + d_{n - 1}x^{n - 1}$, so that $L_{i, j, \mu}(\mathbf{d})  = D^{(\mu)}(\theta_{i, j})$ by the definitions of $D$ and $L_{i, j, \mu}$.
> Let $r_{i, \mu}(n) = \vert D^{(\mu)}(\theta_{i, 1}) \cdots D^{(\mu)}(\theta_{i, d_i}) \vert$ and let $q_i > 0$ be the leading coefficient of $P_i$.
> We have thus
> $$q_i^{n - 1} r_{i, \mu}(n) < q_i^{n - 1} \epsilon_{i, 1, \mu}(n) \cdots \epsilon_{i, d_i, \mu}(n) = O\left(\frac{n^{d_i/2} M(P_i)^{n - 1}}{(M + 1)^{nd_i/\deg(P)}}\right).$$
> It follows that
> $$r_i (n):= q_i^{n - 1} r_{i, 0}(n) \cdots q_i^{n - 1} r_{i, \mu_i - 1}(n) = O\left(\frac{n^{\mu_i d_i/2} M(P_i^{\mu_i})^{n - 1}}{(M + 1)^{n \mu_i d_i/\deg(P)}}\right)$$
> for every $i \in \{1, \dots, k\}$ and hence
> $$r_1(n) \cdots r_k(n) = O\left( n^{\deg(P)/2} (\frac{M}{M + 1})^n\right) = o(1).$$
> Since $\theta_{i, 1}, \dots, \theta_{i, d_i}$ are the roots of $P_i$, we have
> $e_{j, d_i}(\theta_{i, 1}, \dots, \theta_{i, d_i}) \in \frac{1}{q_i} \mathbb{Z}$ for every elementary symmetric polynomial  $e_{j, d_i}$.
> By the above lemma, we know that $q_i^{n - 1} r_{i, \mu}(n) \in \mathbb{N}$ for every $i \in \{1, \dots, d_i\}$ and every $\mu \in \{0, \dots, \mu_i - 1\}$.
> Thus we have  $r_1(n) \cdots r_k(n) \in \mathbb{N}$ and $r_1(n) \cdots r_k(n) = o(1)$,
> which entails that $r_i(n) = r_{i, \mu}(n) = D^{(\mu)}(\theta_{i, j}) = 0$ for all $n$ large enough and for every $i, j$ and $\mu$, as desired.

---

[1] M. Pathiaux, "Sur les multiples de polynômes irréductibles associés à certains nombres algébriques", 1972.
[2] M. Mignotte, "Sur les multiples des polynômes irréductibles", 1975.
[3] E. Bombieri and J. Vaaler, "On Siegel's Lemma", 1984.

Comment: Great, that is exactly what I needed. Jankauskas cites another french paper by Mignotte: "Sur les multiples des polynômes irréductibles" (which seems to be hard to find online). However Pathiaux's work is fine.

Comment: @RobertZ Thanks a lot for your feedback, you are very welcome. I also find it hard to get access to of M. Mignotte's simplified proof. I'll contact you via email if I manage to get a copy. (I have ordered one).

Comment: Thanks, that's very kind of yours